# User variable is giving last assigned values in a Session

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, dynamic-queries

We recently found the re-declaration issue in Mysql. If the query or procedure is called repeatedly in loop it retained last values.

```
SET @ToolType = 'test-Tool1';
SET @ToolType = (select Tool_type from IBP__Tool_type aa inner join IBP__xTool_set bb on aa.Tool_type_id=-1) ;
select @ToolType;

SET @ToolType = 'test-Tool1';
select @ToolType:=Tool_type from IBP__Tool_type aa inner join IBP__xTool_set bb on aa.Tool_type_id=-1;
select @ToolType; -- = OR :=

SET @ToolType = 'test-Tool2';
select Tool_type into @ToolType from IBP__Tool_type aa inner join IBP__xTool_set bb on aa.Tool_type_id=-1;
select @ToolType;
```

**Above code will have Results : (when -1 is not present in tables so the output should be null in all cases)**

- null
- test-tool1
- test-tool2

what is the best way to resolve This Issue.

Comment: It retains the value if the `select` does not return any values.

Answer (score 0):

assign the variable to null before using it each time in query. User Session issues will always store the variable value in Mysql server and cause these issues.

```
SET @ToolType = null;
```

[image]